# update-notifier crashed with sigsegv

Tags: update-notifier

update-notifier crashed with sigsegv on newly installed Ubuntu 22.04.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to click "Send".

Then run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`

You cannot fix a segfault. It's a bug. Clicking "Send" will report the bug to Ubuntu developers.

Comment: thanks issue resolved